# Removing rows with all NA's, from data.frames within a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, na

Example Data:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(1,2,3), c(1, NA, 4), c(NA, NA, NA), c(4,6,7), c(4, 8, NA)))
df2 <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(1,2,3), c(1, NA, 4), c(4,6,7), c(NA, NA, NA), c(4, 8, NA)))

dfList <- list(df1,df2)
colnames <- c("A","B","C") 

dfList[[1]]

  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  1 NA  4
3 NA NA NA
4  4  6  7
5  4  8 NA

dfList[[2]]

  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  1 NA  4
3  4  6  7
4 NA NA NA
5  4  8 NA
```

How do I remove the rows that are empty/have ALL values NA, within each of the data.frames in the list?

Desired outcome:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  1 NA  4
3  4  6  7
4  4  8 NA


  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  1 NA  4
3  4  6  7
4  4  8 NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to iterate over the list and `rowSums` to drop rows with all `NA` values.

```
lapply(dfList, function(x) x[rowSums(!is.na(x)) != 0, ])

#[[1]]
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  1  2  3
#2  1 NA  4
#4  4  6  7
#5  4  8 NA

#[[2]]
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  1  2  3
#2  1 NA  4
#3  4  6  7
#5  4  8 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
map(dfList, remove_empty, which = c("rows"))

[[1]]
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  1 NA  4
4  4  6  7
5  4  8 NA

[[2]]
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  1 NA  4
3  4  6  7
5  4  8 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution with `all()`

```
lapply(dfList, function(d) d[!apply(is.na(d), 1, all),])
```